# AG-Grid & React Hooks: How to call a function in a parent component from a cellRendererFramework component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project that uses ag-grid 25.1.0, and it cannot be updated to a later version. The project has data presented in 2 views, as cards or as a grid, so the data has to be stored in a parent component and is passed down via child components. My problem is that I can't work out how to call a function in the parent component from a button in the grid. The flow from the parent goes: parent > grid > columnDefs > cellRendererFramework and I need to call setAgentData in the parent from the last element in that list. There is a lot of bespoke code in the project so I'm adding a **very** simplified version of it here, leaving out anything that doesn't relate directly to the question.

Parent Component:

```
import Grid from './grid/grid';
....

const Apps = (props) => {
  const [agentData, setAgentData] = useState(props.data);

  return (
    <Grid
      agentData={agentData}
      setAgentData={setAgentData}
    />
  );
};

export default Apps;
```

Grid Component:

```
import { columnDefs } from './columns';
import Grid from 'ag-grid';
...

const Grid = (props) => {
  ...
  
  return (
    <Grid
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      records={props.agentData}
      setAgentData={props.setAgentData} // Unsure if this is how to pass the function call here
    />
  );
};

export default Grid;
```

Column Definition Component:

```
import Toggle from './toggle';
...

export const columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'active',
    cellRendererFramework: Toggle,
    // Unsure how to pass the function call here
    ...
  }
]
```

CellRendererFramework Component:

```
const Toggle = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      value="props.agentData"
      onClick={() => props.setAgentData(!props.agentData)
    />
  );
};

export default Toggle;
```

As I said, this is a very simplified version of the code - all I need to know is how to call setAgentData from the Toggle component. If I've made any mistakes elsewhere, please ignore them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `setAgentData` within `Toggle`, you need to pass it through as a prop. ag-grid allows you to specify the additional parameters to pass through in the `columnDefs` array of objects by adding the `cellRendererParams` property to your objects. As `setAgentData` is only available to you within your `Grid` component and not "Column Definition Component" file, you can `.map()` your array of objects like so to add the `cellRendererParams` to pass through the function:

```js
const Grid = (props) => {
  const columnDefsWithProps = useMemo(() =>  {
    return columnDefs.map(col => col.cellRendererFramework === Toggle
      ? {...col, cellRendererParams: {setAgentData: props.setAgentData}}
      : col
    );
  }, [props.setAgentData]);
  
  return (
    <Grid
      columnDefs={columnDefsWithProps}
      records={props.agentData}
    />
  );
};

export default Grid;
```

I've wrapped the above in a `useMemo()` to avoid rerunning the map on each rerender of `Grid`. If you have many grid items that you need to pass this to you can change the condition in the `.map()`. You may also need to pass through other props such as `agentData` if that is not available currently.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. The only thing I'd add is that the Toggle component has to be imported into both the Grid and Column Definition components.

Comment: @DorianFabre No worries. Using `Toggle` within `Grid` is just a way to identify which object to update to add the `cellRendererParams` property to. Using the `field` key could be another way to do that, `col.field === "active" ? ...`, or using the index of the object is another `i === 0 ? ...` (you can get the index using the second argument of the `.map()` callback)